Is there a French version of this Chinese Language community?
Chinese Language is in English, but is there a French version of this community ?

I doubt there are enough French speakers who can answer your questions on Chinese language.

No unfortunately not, there is no French language version of Chinese StackExchange.
Chinese StackExchange isn't strictly English either though, but it would be best if questions were written in either English or Chinese. Broken English is fine too.

The Forum Apprendre Chinois is a forum about learning Chinese for Francophones.  Even though there's no peer review mechanism, this forum accepts Q&A, so you might find this useful.
